# Problem with classicthesis tables numeration

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, classicthesis

I am using classicthesis to write my thesis. I encounter this problem: my tables are numerated starting from 2. Also in the List of Tables, tables are listed from Table 2. I have checked if there are any table environment before the table that is classified as Table 2, but there aren't!

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: a clean compilation with pdflatex without makeglossaries gives the correct result, i.e. tables are enumerated from 1. After compiling makeglossaries, at the first round of pdflatex, tables are enumerated correctly, but at the second round of pdflatex tables are enumerated from 2!
Seems that makeglossaries introduces a table

EDIT 2: here is a working example

error can be replicated in the following way:

pdflatex thesis

pdflatex thesis

makeglossaries thesis

pdflatex thesis   (at this execution tables are still enumerated correctly in the lot)

pdflatex thesis   (here comes the error)

**thesis.tex**

```
%thesis.tex
\documentclass[ twoside,openright, titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,% letterpaper a4paper
            footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
            BCOR=25mm,fontsize=11pt,a4paper,%
            american,%
            ]{scrreprt}

%********************************************************************
% Note: Make all your adjustments in here
%*******************************************************
\input{classicthesis-config}
%\usepackage{lmodern}

%\pagestyle{plain}
%\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{plain}

\clearscrheadfoot
\lehead{\headmark}
\rohead{\headmark}
\lefoot[\llap{\small\thepage\kern2em}]{\llap{\small\thepage\kern2em}}
\rofoot[\rlap{\small\kern2em\pagemark}]{\rlap{\small\kern2em\pagemark}}


%\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}


%********************************************************************
% Hyphenation
%*******************************************************
%\hyphenation{put special hyphenation here}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{mac}{MAC}{Media Acces Control}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\selectlanguage{american} % american ngerman
%\renewcommand*{\bibname}{new name}
%\setbibpreamble{}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
%********************************************************************
% Frontmatter
%*******************************************************
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

%*******************************************************
% Table of Contents
%*******************************************************
%\phantomsection
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{tableofcontents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % <-- 2 includes up to subsections in the ToC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % <-- 3 numbers up to subsubsections
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\tableofcontents 
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
%*******************************************************
% List of Figures and of the Tables
%*******************************************************
\clearpage

\begingroup 
\let\clearpage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
%*******************************************************
% List of Figures
%*******************************************************    
%\phantomsection 
\refstepcounter{dummy}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\pdfbookmark[1]{\listfigurename}{lof}
\listoffigures

\vspace*{8ex}

%*******************************************************
% List of Tables
%*******************************************************
%\phantomsection 
\refstepcounter{dummy}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\pdfbookmark[1]{\listtablename}{lot}
\listoftables
    
\vspace*{8ex}

   
%*******************************************************
% Acronyms
%*******************************************************
%\phantomsection           

\refstepcounter{dummy}
\pdfbookmark[1]{Acronyms}{acronyms}
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Acronyms}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Acronyms}}
\printglossaries

\endgroup

\cleardoublepage



%********************************************************************
% Mainmatter
%*******************************************************
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\setcounter{page}{90}


\chapter{introduction}
\gls{mac}

\begin{table}
\caption{tab 1}
\label{tab:1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{tab 2}
\label{tab:2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**classicthesis-config.tex**

```
% classicthesis-config.tex 
% formerly known as loadpackages.sty, classicthesis-ldpkg.sty, and classicthesis-preamble.sty 
% Use it at the beginning of your ClassicThesis.tex, or as a LaTeX Preamble 
% in your ClassicThesis.{tex,lyx} with \input{classicthesis-config
% ****************************************************************************************************  
% If you like the classicthesis, then I would appreciate a postcard. 
% My address can be found in the file ClassicThesis.pdf. A collection 
% of the postcards I received so far is available online at 
% http://postcards.miede.de
% ****************************************************************************************************

% ****************************************************************************************************
% 1. Configure classicthesis for your needs here, e.g., remove "drafting" below 
% in order to deactivate the time-stamp on the pages
% ****************************************************************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{eulerchapternumbers,listings,%drafting,%
             pdfspacing,%floatperchapter,%linedheaders,%
             subfig,beramono,eulermath,parts}{classicthesis}                                        
% ********************************************************************
% Available options for classicthesis.sty 
% (see ClassicThesis.pdf for more information):
% drafting
% parts nochapters linedheaders
% eulerchapternumbers beramono eulermath pdfspacing minionprospacing
% tocaligned dottedtoc manychapters
% listings floatperchapter subfig
% ********************************************************************

% ********************************************************************
% Triggers for this config
% ******************************************************************** 
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{enable-backrefs} % enable backrefs in the bibliography
\setboolean{enable-backrefs}{false} % true false
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 2. Personal data and user ad-hoc commands
% ****************************************************************************************************
\newcommand{\myTitle}{a title\xspace}
\newcommand{\mySubtitle}{\xspace}
\newcommand{\myDegree}{Mr.\xspace}
\newcommand{\myName}{xxx\xspace}
\newcommand{\myProf}{yyy\xspace}
\newcommand{\myOtherProf}{zzz\xspace}
\newcommand{\mySupervisor}{www\xspace}
\newcommand{\myFaculty}{Telecommunication Engineering\xspace}
\newcommand{\myDepartment}{kkk\xspace}
\newcommand{\myUni}{University of jjj\xspace}
\newcommand{\myLocation}{ggg\xspace}
\newcommand{\myTime}{August 2015\xspace}
\newcommand{\myVersion}{version 4.1\xspace}

\newcommand{\aPTX}{{\bf p}_{\rm tx}}
\newcommand{\aPALPHA}[1]{P_{\bf #1}(\alpha)}
\newcommand{\aM}[1]{\mathbf{M}^{(\mathbf{#1})}}
\newcommand{\aVALSTEP}{{\rm v}_{\rm max}}
\newcommand{\aS}[1]{{\bf s}^{({\bf #1})}}
\newcommand{\aT}[1]{{\bf T}^{({\bf #1})}}

\newcommand{\vup}{\vspace{-1mm}}



% ********************************************************************
% Setup, finetuning, and useful commands
% ********************************************************************
\newcounter{dummy} % necessary for correct hyperlinks (to index, bib, etc.)
\newlength{\abcd} % for ab..z string length calculation
\providecommand{\mLyX}{L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\@}
\newcommand{\ie}{i.\,e.}
\newcommand{\Ie}{I.\,e.}
\newcommand{\eg}{e.\,g.}
\newcommand{\Eg}{E.\,g.} 
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 3. Loading some handy packages
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ******************************************************************** 
% Packages with options that might require adjustments
% ******************************************************************** 
\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}   % latin9 (ISO-8859-9) = latin1+"Euro sign"
\usepackage{inputenc}               

%\PassOptionsToPackage{ngerman,american}{babel}   % change this to your language(s)
% Spanish languages need extra options in order to work with this template
%\PassOptionsToPackage{spanish,es-lcroman}{babel}
\usepackage[english]{babel}                 

\PassOptionsToPackage{square,numbers}{natbib}
\usepackage{natbib}             

\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}       % math environments and more by the AMS 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\usepackage{dsfont}


% ******************************************************************** 
% General useful packages
% ******************************************************************** 
\PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc} % T2A for cyrillics
\usepackage{fontenc}     
\usepackage{textcomp} % fix warning with missing font shapes
\usepackage{scrhack} % fix warnings when using KOMA with listings package          
\usepackage{xspace} % to get the spacing after macros right  
\usepackage{mparhack} % get marginpar right
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % fixes some LaTeX stuff 

%\PassOptionsToPackage{printonlyused,smaller}{acronym}
%   \usepackage{acronym} % nice macros for handling all acronyms in the thesis

%%\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\textssc{#1}} % for MinionPro
%\renewcommand{\bflabel}[1]{{#1}\hfill} % fix the list of acronyms
% ****************************************************************************************************

% siunitx
\usepackage[mode=text]{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-weight=true, detect-family=true}

%algorithms
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}





% ****************************************************************************************************
% 4. Setup floats: tables, (sub)figures, and captions
% ****************************************************************************************************
\usepackage{tabularx} % better tables
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt} % increase table row height
\newcommand{\tableheadline}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myfloatalign}{\centering} % to be used with each float for alignment
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=hang,font=small}
\usepackage{subfig}  
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 5. Setup code listings
% ****************************************************************************************************
\usepackage{listings} 
%\lstset{emph={trueIndex,root},emphstyle=\color{BlueViolet}}%\underbar} % for special keywords
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,%C++,
    keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue},%\bfseries,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    %identifierstyle=\color{NavyBlue},
    commentstyle=\color{Green}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\rmfamily,
    numbers=none,%left,%
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,%\tiny
    stepnumber=5,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frameround=ftff,
    frame=single,
    belowcaptionskip=.75\baselineskip
    %frame=L
} 
% ****************************************************************************************************             


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 6. PDFLaTeX, hyperreferences and citation backreferences
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ********************************************************************
% Using PDFLaTeX
% ********************************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex,hyperfootnotes=false,pdfpagelabels}{hyperref}
    \usepackage{hyperref}  % backref linktocpage pagebackref
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfadjustspacing=1 
%\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex}{graphicx}
    \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx} 
    \graphicspath{{./gfx/}}


% ********************************************************************
% Setup the style of the backrefs from the bibliography
% (translate the options to any language you use)
% ********************************************************************
\newcommand{\backrefnotcitedstring}{\relax}%(Not cited.)
\newcommand{\backrefcitedsinglestring}[1]{(Cited on page~#1.)}
\newcommand{\backrefcitedmultistring}[1]{(Cited on pages~#1.)}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{enable-backrefs}}%
{%
        \PassOptionsToPackage{hyperpageref}{backref}
        \usepackage{backref} % to be loaded after hyperref package 
           \renewcommand{\backreftwosep}{ and~} % separate 2 pages
           \renewcommand{\backreflastsep}{, and~} % separate last of longer list
           \renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}  % disable standard
           \renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{% detailed backref
              \ifcase #1 %
                 \backrefnotcitedstring%
              \or%
                 \backrefcitedsinglestring{#2}%
              \else%
                 \backrefcitedmultistring{#2}%
              \fi}%
}{\relax}    



% ********************************************************************
% Hyperreferences
% ********************************************************************
\hypersetup{%
    %draft, % = no hyperlinking at all (useful in b/w printouts)
    colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV,%
    % uncomment the following line if you want to have black links (e.g., for printing)
    %colorlinks=false, linktocpage=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV,% 
    breaklinks=true, pdfpagemode=UseNone, pageanchor=true, pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,%
    plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1,%
    hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O,%nesting=true,%frenchlinks,%
    urlcolor=webbrown, linkcolor=RoyalBlue, citecolor=webgreen, %pagecolor=RoyalBlue,%
    %urlcolor=Black, linkcolor=Black, citecolor=Black, %pagecolor=Black,%
    pdftitle={\myTitle},%
    pdfauthor={\textcopyright\ \myName, \myUni, \myFaculty},%
    pdfsubject={},%
    pdfkeywords={},%
    pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX},%
    pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref and classicthesis}%
}   


\usepackage[style=long,nolist,acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}


% ********************************************************************
% Setup autoreferences
% ********************************************************************
% There are some issues regarding autorefnames
% http://www.ureader.de/msg/136221647.aspx
% https://texfaq.org/FAQ-latexwords
% you have to redefine the makros for the 
% language you use, e.g., american, ngerman
% (as chosen when loading babel/AtBeginDocument)
% ********************************************************************
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{babel}%
    {%
       \addto\extrasamerican{%
                    \renewcommand*{\figureautorefname}{Figure}%
                    \renewcommand*{\tableautorefname}{Table}%
                    \renewcommand*{\partautorefname}{Part}%
                    \renewcommand*{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}%
                    \renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Section}%
                    \renewcommand*{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}%
                    \renewcommand*{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}%     
                }%
%       \addto\extrasngerman{% 
%                   \renewcommand*{\paragraphautorefname}{Absatz}%
%                   \renewcommand*{\subparagraphautorefname}{Unterabsatz}%
%                   \renewcommand*{\footnoteautorefname}{Fu\"snote}%
%                   \renewcommand*{\FancyVerbLineautorefname}{Zeile}%
%                   \renewcommand*{\theoremautorefname}{Theorem}%
%                   \renewcommand*{\appendixautorefname}{Anhang}%
%                   \renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}{Gleichung}%        
%                   \renewcommand*{\itemautorefname}{Punkt}%
%               }%  
            % Fix to getting autorefs for subfigures right (thanks to Belinda Vogt for changing the definition)
            \providecommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname}%             
    }{\relax}
\makeatother


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 7. Last calls before the bar closes
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ********************************************************************
% Development Stuff
% ********************************************************************
\listfiles



%\PassOptionsToPackage{l2tabu,orthodox,abort}{nag}
%   \usepackage{nag}
%\PassOptionsToPackage{warning, all}{onlyamsmath}
%   \usepackage{onlyamsmath}

% ********************************************************************
% Last, but not least...
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage{classicthesis} 
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 8. Further adjustments (experimental)
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ********************************************************************
% Changing the text area
% ********************************************************************
%\linespread{1.05} % a bit more for Palatino
%\areaset[current]{312pt}{761pt} % 686 (factor 2.2) + 33 head + 42 head \the\footskip
%\setlength{\marginparwidth}{7em}%
%\setlength{\marginparsep}{2em}%

% ********************************************************************
% Using different fonts
% ********************************************************************
%\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts} % oldstyle notextcomp
%\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
%\usepackage{hfoldsty} % Computer Modern with osf
%\usepackage[light,condensed,math]{iwona}
%\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{iwona}
%\usepackage{lmodern} % <-- no osf support :-(
%\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign} <-- no osf support :-(
% ****************************************************************************************************
```

Thank you!

Comment: Apparently you have invisible tables in your invisible code here ;-)

Comment: If you post an example code which reproduces the error, people can try it and look for a solution

Comment: Where is `classthesis-config`?

Comment: It is a file given in classicthesis: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/
I did few mod.

Comment: classthesis-config? is not it classicthesis-config? It is given after thesis.tex

Comment: I reported it after thesis.tex;
the original is in the link I reported, but since I did some adjustments I reported the whole code as well.

Comment: @alain: I think it's the fact that `acronym` uses a `longtable` to display the list of acronomys, which in fact uses automatically a `\caption` and that increases the table counter, since `\printglossaries` is right at the start, so the real tables start with a table number of two

Comment: What do you suggest to fix the 'problem'?

Comment: @alain: See the fix in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to this:
Either

- you set `style=super` (for example) as glossary style  (easy)
- you define a new style based on the `long` style, say `longacro` in which `longtable` is replaced by `longtable*`, which doesn't use the table counter and the ordinary counter values are not changed by this. ('difficult')

I have done the more difficult way here.

In addition I commented out the unnecessary `dummy` counter stuff.

---

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright, titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,% letterpaper a4paper
            footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
            BCOR=25mm,fontsize=11pt,a4paper,%
            american,%
            ]{scrreprt}

%********************************************************************
% Note: Make all your adjustments in here
%*******************************************************
\input{classicthesis-config}
%\usepackage{lmodern}

%\pagestyle{plain}
%\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{plain}

\clearscrheadfoot
\lehead{\headmark}
\rohead{\headmark}
\lefoot[\llap{\small\thepage\kern2em}]{\llap{\small\thepage\kern2em}}
\rofoot[\rlap{\small\kern2em\pagemark}]{\rlap{\small\kern2em\pagemark}}


%\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}


%********************************************************************
% Hyphenation
%*******************************************************
%\hyphenation{put special hyphenation here}

\makeglossaries


\newglossarystyle{longacro}{%
\setglossarystyle{long}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{%
  \begin{longtable*}{lp{\glsdescwidth}}}%
  {\end{longtable*}}% 
}


\newacronym{mac}{MAC}{Media Acces Control}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\selectlanguage{american} % american ngerman
%\renewcommand*{\bibname}{new name}
%\setbibpreamble{}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
%********************************************************************
% Frontmatter
%*******************************************************
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

%*******************************************************
% Table of Contents
%*******************************************************
%\phantomsection
%\refstepcounter{dummy}
\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{tableofcontents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % <-- 2 includes up to subsections in the ToC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % <-- 3 numbers up to subsubsections
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\tableofcontents 
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
%*******************************************************
% List of Figures and of the Tables
%*******************************************************
\clearpage

\begingroup 
\let\clearpage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
%*******************************************************
% List of Figures
%*******************************************************    
%\phantomsection 
%\refstepcounter{dummy}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\pdfbookmark[1]{\listfigurename}{lof}
\listoffigures

\vspace*{8ex}

%*******************************************************
% List of Tables
%*******************************************************
%\phantomsection 
%\refstepcounter{dummy}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\pdfbookmark[1]{\listtablename}{lot}
\listoftables

\vspace*{8ex}


%*******************************************************
% Acronyms
%*******************************************************
%\phantomsection           

%\refstepcounter{dummy}
\pdfbookmark[1]{Acronyms}{acronyms}
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Acronyms}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Acronyms}}
\printacronyms[style=longacro]

\endgroup

\cleardoublepage



%********************************************************************
% Mainmatter
%*******************************************************
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\setcounter{page}{90}


%\chapter{introduction}
\gls{mac}

\begin{table}
\caption{tab 1}
\label{tab:1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{tab 2}
\label{tab:2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a package I need to add? \printacronyms gives me problems...

Comment: @alain: No, I did not add any package. Do you have some old `glossaries` version?

Comment: I have installed tex live 2013. 
Anyway, this is how glossaries is imported in my code:
\usepackage[style=long,nolist,acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

Comment: @alain: Yes, I know -- I did not change that line

Comment: Ok, I have checked: my version of glossaries.sty is 3.05. \printacronyms has been added since 3.11. I am updating texlive right now. I'll let you know!

Comment: I have finally updated. Now it works! Thank you Christian!

Comment: @alain: Alright, happy TeXing then